# Download string from website, check each line if it contains string

Tags: c#, string, winforms, web, download

I have created a simple page that contains plain text like this:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
```

And I made a c# Winform app that contains a textbox
Textbox text is like

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

I want to check if a textbox line contains any of downloaded string from my website

here's what i tried but doesn't work

```cs
int pub = 0;
int priv  = 0;
WebClient data = new WebClient();
string reply = data.DownloadString("http://mytoosupd.000webhostapp.com/public-keys.html");

for (int i=0; i < textBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
{
  if (textBox1.Lines[i].Contains(reply + "\n"))
  {
    pub++;
    label5.Text = pub.ToString();
    continue;
  } 
  else if (!textBox1.Lines[i].Contains(reply))
  {
    priv++;
    label4.Text = priv.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: check your variables with a debugger!! you compare you local winform lines with the whole downloaded multiple lines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Split`, `Intersect`, `Any` would be easy enough

```
string reply = data.DownloadString(..);

var result = reply
   .Split(new[] {"\r\n", "\r", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
   .Intersect(textBox1.Lines)
   .Any();

Debug.WriteLine($"Found = {result}");
```

**Update**

```
// to get a list of the intersected lines, call `ToList()` instead
var list = reply
   .Split(new[] {"\r\n", "\r", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
   .Intersect(textBox1.Lines)
   .ToList();


// list.Count() to get the count
// use this list where ever you like
// someTextBox.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, list);
// or potentially
// someTextBox.Lines = list.ToArray();
```

Comment: Where i put this?

Comment: Wherever you like, `Result` will contain a bool (true/false) of whether the reply has any intersection with the lines in the textbox

Comment: Ok got it, Now i want to make int of how many checked lines and the checked lines paste them into another textbox?

Comment: @HarethMK, instead of `Any` use `ToList` this will get you the intersected lines I.e the one that are the same between the 2 sources. you can put the result in a new text box, or call Count to get the... well the count

Comment: I did it but it says can't convert list to string, I made it toString but textbox2 ( result ) is empty

Comment: @HarethMK ok add more examples, however ill let you take it from here ;)

Comment: Thank you for your time, I have 2 labels, One is Found and other is Not-Found

Comment: After checking the textbox1 lines with my website text, I want to add to Label Found a total lines found in the website text, and Not-Found is not found on the website text

Comment: Like this: Found: 0, Not-Found:0. I have a textbox:[line1, line2] my website [line3] --- checked button clicked. Found:0, Not-Found: 2. and the same for found

Comment: @HarethMK this is a little beyond the scope of the original question, and now more of how to add data to controls on a winforms app, maybe you can ask another question

Comment: No it's the same check the picture i added to my question